# Firebase remove authenticated users created with "test phone numbers" after some time?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using smartphone authentication feature from firebase to register my users, but some of my users do not receive SMS codes in their mobile phones(signal problems...), and sometimes i really need these customers, so i create a test SMS code (using the real phone number, so they can receive SMS in the future). When they authenticate with the fake SMS Code, firebase create an ID with an UID and i can login again later with no problems, but happened that 3 times these users created with the fake number feature and with an valid and registered UID were deleted from the authentication list after some time, i cant find them anymore, and when i register them again, a new UID is generated, is this a real behavior of firebase, exclude test numbers UID generated after some time?

Comment: Hi Lothar, could you be more clear and concise in your question? Each time you create a user with Authentication, a new User with a unique ID (uid) is created.

Comment: @LucasDavidFerrero, hi lucas, yes, a new unique ID is created when i register a phone, but when i use the feature 'Telephone numbers for testing'(here i can create a fake SMS code to register and get a UID) feature from Smartphone authentication, sometimes firebase delete some UID created from this feature(fake number). i want know if its normal.